# Gap between main view and scroll view using Auto Layout in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm experiencing some trouble managing a scroll view embed inside a navigation view controller. I'm using Auto Layout and I'll try to explain the problem the best I can.

1. I embed a scroll view in the controller's main view and pinned the top, left, bottom and right borders to main view's borders.
2. I embed a standard `UIView` inside the scroll view and gave it a fixed height of 800 points. This should act as a container for all my controls (let's name it *content view*). Then again I pinned its top, left, bottom and right borders to the scroll view's borders. Because the bottom space constraint of scroll view's descendant view was negative, I adjusted it bringing it back to 0.
3. For the width, I CTRL-dragged from the content view to the main view and added a *Equal widths* constraint.
4. Finally, I added an image view and placed it at the top center of my content view adding some further trivial constraint.

The storyboard for the situation I've just depicted is shown above (in the document outline you should see all the constraints I've defined).

[image: storyboard]

My scroll view works, it scrolls fine and the image view is well-centered where it's supposed to be. However, there's a gap between the end of the navigation bar and the start of the scroll view and I can't figure out why. It seems to be as high as the navigation bar, but I have no idea about how to fix it. The image shown below should make you understand what I'm talking about (the content view is highlighted in grey for clarity).

[image: gap]

I didn't write a single line of code to achieve this result. I would really appreciate any kind of help and I'm ready to give you all the information you need to help me address the problem.

Comment: I think you should uncheck `Adjust scrollview Insets` of your viewcontroller

Comment: @EICaptain Thank you, that solved the problem. Didn't know it could be so easy. Please turn your comment into an answer so I'd have the chance to approve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should **uncheck** `Adjust Scrollview Insets` property of your viewcontroller to get rid of this....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to uncheck Adjust Scrollview Insets